# This bar has notes spanning farther than my fingers can reach on piano. How should it be played?

Tags: piano, fingering

On the following bar of music from "Thank You for Being a Friend", I don't know how to play the specified notes with my limited human hands, particularly the first two beats. I don't see a way to sustain the half notes in the treble clef, while executing the 8th notes that follow:

[image: measure corresponding to "And if you threw a par -"]

If this is possible to play, please explain how one would position their fingers to play it.

**Edit:** fixed grammar and spelling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is this piano finger stretch remotely possible for anyone?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/65896/how-is-this-piano-finger-stretch-remotely-possible-for-anyone)

Comment: I guess if the answer is to use the sustain pedal, I'd like more people to confirm that. I don't personally like the answer because it will change the sound of the 8th notes, causing their tones to overlap.

Comment: I take it you can't hit the low G and the three half-notes with your left hand?   Anyway, this  not-a-pianist suggests putting on the Sus but releasing it part-way thru the second beat (assuming 4/4).  The audience will "hear" the chord via neuro-recall .

Comment: Yeah, I've tried to hit as much of the first chord as possible with my left hand. No dice. Bonus points for using the term "neuro-recall".

Comment: Of course, part of the answer is "in some situations, you can excuse yourself from doubling the melody"...

Comment: Yes, the sustain pedal is the way to do it. Release the pedal when you get to the F# on the word "you/we", and then reapply it on the next chord. That will keep the sound of the eighth notes fairly clean.

Comment: First of all take into account this is not an original piano track but an arrangement. Arrangements often include some compromises or shortcuts. In this case piano doubles the vocal melody, which is not the case in the original. If you don't like the choices and compromises the arranger made, go ahead find another way which sounds better to you. If you want to play the notes as they are without sustain pedal, you could use sostenuto pedal....

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - 'putting on the sus' = using the damper pedal.

Comment: If you were playing on a piano with a sostenuto pedal (e.g. a grand piano, or an electronic one), could that be used to sustain the low chord without also sustaining the melody?

Comment: (However, I agree that exact reproduction of the notes precisely as written isn't the point of this kind of accompaniment. Depending on the singer, you might not even play the melody at all!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're accompanying a competent singer, the practical answer may be that the 8th notes don't get played at all!   This is a song copy, not a meticulously composed piano etude.   It aims to give information about what's going on musically - you are allowed and expected to use it only as a guide.

But actually, with a judicious touch of pedal, you could play all those notes quite effectively. You'd maybe want to change pedal on the second bass note.   That gives the chord almost all its written length.